# 'handleChange not defined' in a React Component I created

Tags: reactjs

I am attempting to use emailJS in a React Modal I have created. The modal was working just fine but the action is not. Below is my Email Component that gives me a console error of 'handleChange is not defined' in the console upon clicking the Modal. However, I have defined it on line 18.

```
import React from 'react';
import emailjs from 'emailjs-com';

export default class ContactUs extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''      
    };

    this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    emailjs
      .sendForm(
        'gmail', 
        'portfoliotemplate', 
        '.contact_form_class', 
        'user_wQPetSHncS1Xuyip0lihm'
      )
      .then()
      .catch();
    this.setState({
      name: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form
          onSubmit={this.handleChange}
          className='contact-form'
        >
          <label>Name : </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            id='name'
            name='name'
            placeholder='Your name'
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
          <label>Phone : </label>
          <input
            type='number'
            id='phone'
            name='phone'
            placeholder='Your phone number'
            value={this.state.phone}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
          <label>Email : </label>
          <input
            type='text'
            id='email'
            name='email'
            placeholder='Your email'
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <br />
          <label>Message : </label>
          <input
            type='textarea'
            id='message'
            name='message'
            placeholder='How may I be of assistance?'
            value={this.state.message}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
            <input
            type='submit'
            />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Any feedback or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is with these lines:

```js
this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = handleSubmit.bind(this);
```

You missed the `this` before your binding statements. That means `handleChange` is undefined, so your binding is actually causing `this.handleChange` to be undefined as well.

To reference a class method, you would need to change it to `this.handleChange.bind(this)`.

*However*, the binding is unnecessary since you are using arrow syntax. Class methods defined using arrow syntax will get `this` from scope, instead of by the context of the method call. So the easiest solution is to just remove the binds.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using fat operator while declaring function handleChange and handleSubmit, than you should not bind that in constructor. So, remove binding from constructor and your constructor will be like as follows

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: '',
      phone: '',
      email: '',
      message: ''      
    };

     // this.handleChange = handleChange.bind(this);
    // this.handleSubmit = handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```